# Custom Migration options for iCloud Core Data store

Tags: ios, core-data, core-data-migration

The documentation (as of iOS 8) says only lightweight migrations may be performed on an iCloud backed Core Data store. What options are there if one still needs to perform custom migrations afterwards?

Context: we are about to move to iCloud with our Core Data app, but expect future major schema changes what would still need custom migration via mapped fields, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only option is lightweight migration if you are using iCloud.  If you need to do a structural change to the model then it must be doable with a lightweight.

You can do alterations to the data after the migration but the migration itself is stuck as lightweight forever going forward.

If you get stuck then you are left with the option of exporting all of the data (perhaps into another Core Data store) and the importing the data again into iCloud as if it were new.